# Do suspended processes still use up CPU/RAM?

Tags: windows, process, ram, internals

I am wondering, if you suspend a process, does it still use the RAM/CPU or does it just free all used RAM and the CPU?

Comment: This site is about programming only there is another site for OS scheduling

Comment: Well it is technically programming. I want to know if suspending processes with SuspendProcess would increase the performance because the RAM is freed and it does not do any CPU cycles. And because there are more knowledgeable people here

Comment: You might have seen processes getting suspended in Task Manager, but it is pretty doubtful that you've seen a SuspendProcess function.  There is no such function built into the OS.  Show us how you do it.

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself wrong. I was talking about the exported function NtSuspendProcess from ntdll that makes a syscall to the kernelmode version: https://i.imgur.com/MHxpSVr.png

Comment: But I know what you mean, with the documented winapi alone you can use SuspendThread to suspend the current running thread, but I was asking for a way to not close the process, but dump all the memory it has in the RAM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suspending all threads in a process will prevent the threads from receiving more CPU time so once any remaining kernel interrupts/operations have completed the process will not consume any CPU power until threads are resumed. The undocumented API to suspend a process simply suspends all the threads in the process while holding a process related lock.

A suspended Win32 process does not release any memory but on a system with little free physical RAM, parts of the application can be moved from RAM to the page file to free up RAM for use by other active applications. [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx) can be called to force a reduction of pages in the processes working set.

UWP/Store applications have a higher level type of suspension where the application is given a small time window to save its state and then the entire process **might** be terminated. A new process is started when the user switches back to the application if it was terminated.

> The system attempts to keep your app and its data in memory while it's suspended. However, if the system does not have the resources to keep your app in memory, [it will terminate your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).